# Blazor server - how to prevent page render on the layout level

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, .net-8.0, page-lifecycle

I have a Blazor Server app in .net8. There are many pages that share common parameter in the route, have common base page and layout:

**PageA**

```
@page "/{folder}/files
@inherits MyBasePage

<div>@folderModel.Files</div>
```

**PageB**

```
@page "/{folder}/users
@inherits MyBasePage

<div>@folderModel.Users</div>
```

**Base page**

```
MyBasePage {
  [Parameter]
  public string folder { get; set; }

  protected FolderModel folderModel { get; private set; }

  protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
  {
    await base.OnInitializedAsync();
    folderModel = await someService.GetFolderData(folder);
  }
}
```

It may happen that a folder object is deleted from the system and I want to display a "Not found" content in this case. How can do it and in general prevent rendering/initializing all pages (A, B, ...) when `folderData` is not found (null)? I tried adding some logic around this to the **Layout**:

```
...
if (folderWasFound)
{
  @Body
}
else
{
  <div>Folder not found</div>
}
...
```

but I still need to add `if (folderModel is not null) ...` to all pages to prevent null reference errors. The `folderWasFound` is shared from page to layout via scoped service. Also Layout's `OnInitializedAsync` seems to be executed **after** the page's `OnInitializedAsync` (which I can understand). Are there any other alternatives that will save me all the `if`s in pages A,B,...?

I know I can intercept route values (`folder` in this case) in the Layout initialization itself, but still the initialization order makes it useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Throw an exception when the folder is NotFound and setup an [`<ErrorBoundary>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-8.0#error-boundaries) at some higher level (maybe MainLayout).

Comment: Nice tip, I will read up and definitely give it a try.

Comment: Works really well. Accepting the answer. However this feature produced another issue: when going to page C without `folder` in the URL I set "no folder" when that new page loads. This state is stored in a scoped service (which holds the app state in the circuit). Then suddenly Blazor decides to repaint page B (which still expects folder to be there, but it is not, as page C wiped it out). So I have to put `if`s all over the place again :D So disappointing, no idea where this repaint comes from. It doesn't happen if I remove <ErrorBoundary>.

Comment: T%hat sounds like a different problem. I can't picture it from this, see if you can make a [mre]. Do you have any `async void`  ?

Comment: I nailed it, totally different issue. It happened when I was pushing `<CascadeParameter>` from layout to page body. When I let the base page obtain those params on its own from an injected service things went back to normal.